# How do I make UITableview cells reload across three levels?

Tags: uitableview, ios6

I have an app structure that includes `UITableViews` as shown below. The project is a Core Data app with two entities, and about a dozen attributes.

In the subdetail, there are some `UIPickers`. When the picker items are selected, the change is reflected in the core data model, and in the Root VC. The change is not reflected in the sub detail view itself, nor in the detail view.

I am pushing and popping each VC, passing the entity value between each VC. I go from A to B to C and back.

I will update the question with code snippets if requested.

Thanks

[image]

I have been trying to figure what's happening here for two days, and think it's time to ask for help.

Comment: @dda, thanks for the edits.. How do I accept them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible Explanation of What's Going On**

Without seeing your code, I can only guess, but this is what I think is happening. Your rootViewController is properly listening for changes to the coreData model. You are either directly listening for `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` or have implemented the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`. Or more likely, you are properly performing a fetch in `viewWillAppear` in the rootViewController. However, it is likely that you are not doing any of these things in the Detail or Sub-Detail viewControllers.

**Concrete Suggestions**

1. Call `performFetch` and `[tableView reloadData]` in the Detail and Sub-Detail viewWillAppear so that they will refresh the data from coreData.
2. It is even better to implement `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` so that changes to the coreData model are automagically reflected in the UITableView.

Comment: Eddie, I think you've nailed it. I'm not listening for changes in those controllers. Let me add that.. If I can confirm, I will mark this as done!! I really appreciate you taking the time to try to understand..